# Dialog/tooltip for 'protect' button misaligned on narrow screens

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tooltips, protected-questions

On a narrow screen, the 'protect' button sometimes wraps to the next line of the so-called 'post menu'; if you click it, the resulting dialog/tooltip can become misaligned. On Safari, this happens on widths of about 746 pixels or lower (when the post has been edited, that is).

[image]

Comment: I guess the "tooltip" is not allowed to float further to the left. Or the protect link should not wrap to the next line. Without close vote privileges this would all be fine. Another sign high-rep users are causing problems on the sites ..

Comment: how narrow? I vaguely remember a minimum supported resolution

Comment: Is this on the repsonsive or mobile design?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Our popovers are a [design system component](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/popovers/). They use [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org) under the hood, which supports overflow protection—arrows moving closer to their target element—but we’ve yet to implement it. It’s on our list, but no promise on a timeline. Overflow protection *should* solve this.

Comment: This is working now as expected (at least by me): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sMDfVzBQfwM

Comment: Nice. What a follow-up!